# Android settings like activity, without SharedPreference

Tags: android

I need to create an activity that must be a lot like a settings activity, with a list of clickable items.

What I need is a set of view like CheckBoxPreference, EditTextPreference and DialogPreference in order to let the user set some values.

Anyway I don't want to save the values inside SharedPreference. I need to save them inside another object.

Which is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the reason you do not want to use SharedPreferences?

Comment: because they are not "preference". They are only fields of an object that I want to create and then save to DB

Comment: @Antonio If you want to save them in DB then read my post.

Comment: Why not use regular CheckBox and EditText then? I fail to see the advantage of using a DialogPreferences over a regular Dialog in this case.

Comment: I'd like to have the whole PreferenceScreen facilities: avoid manual event bindings, use the already available custom Dialog like EditTextPreference or ListPreference, that also keeps their state. edit: now, i'm checking for the preference "persistent" attribute. Maybe this can help?...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to save the value in `SharedPreference.

Alternative options.

1 [Sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

2 [File](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) in internal or external memory.

I recommend to use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: the problem is not how to save something, is related to the UI. I want something like a settings activity, but I don't need to save the values inside the SharedPreference. I want to manage the values by myself, and set them inside my object instance. I don't want to rewrite DialogPreference, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a settings activity, let it save to shared preferences, populate your object from shared preferences, then clear the shared preferences.

Comment: If no other ways are available, I think I will use this approach, even if it is a little bit dirty. Thanks